# Authenticate Angular JS application by Node JS with JWT Token

Tags: angularjs, node.js, url-rewriting

I am new on node and angular programming and trying out authentication using node JS and JWT Token before load angular JS application. If authentication is fail then node should redirect un-authorization page else redirect to angular js application.

We have stick with Node, angular and JWT token as per our architecture.

I would like to give here our authentication flow

1. Call angular application from our .net application where we pass token in session storage.
2. Once we are in angular then authenticate with JWT token.
3. If user refresh the page then request should come on Node authentication otherwise request should work based on angular routing.

I used authentication using node as well as url-rewriting but no luck yet.

Please suggest.

Comment: This might help for nodeJS,  https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken